# Is "gonna have to" an Americanism?

Tags: grammar, american-english, dialects, will-be-going

First of all, I have read the answers about "gonna have to" usage, and they are quite clear:

> [*I am gonna have to vs I have to*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/i-am-gonna-have-to-vs-i-have-to)

and

> [why-prefix-a-request-with-im-going-to-have-to-ask-you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39799/why-prefix-a-request-with-im-going-to-have-to-ask-you)

The answers say that the extra words work as a politeness device. OK.

But I have heard *gonna have to* only from American English speakers, so my question is: Is it an Americanism?

Comment: Apparently the "[going to have to ask](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+to+have+to+ask&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)" construction is not exactly unknown in the British corpus.

Comment: @Robusto. Thanks for the google book search trick. Do you know if there a way to superimpose two graphs - one for AmE and another for BrE. Also, just to clarify - I have only heard these experssions from TV or from people who are originally from States. Never seen these expressions in books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one example of a tendency for *going to* to occur as *gonna* in speech, and it is not confined to American English. It’s a semi-modal verb and one of the devices that English has to express the future.

Comment: thanks Barrie. I know that "gonna" is shortened or simplified version of "going to", but my question was about "gonna have to" as a whole. For some reason I have only heard it from a AmE speakers and when I was watching American TV few years ago, so I decided it was American English. Just wanted to confirm if it is true or not.

Comment: @Mitten. I can assure you that as a speaker of British English I'm quite capable of using it myself.